# Chalkboard fails to launch component

Tags: redhawksdr

I've recently Installed CentOS 6.6 and installed the x64 rpms from the github site. When I try to drag any component from the Palette to the chalkboard, I get an error like below:
'Launching SigGen_1' has encountered a problem. 
Failed to launch SigGent_1

Details:
Timed out waiting for component to start. SigGen_1
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Comment: Sometimes running in the REDAWK Python sandbox will yield more detailed error information.  Give this a try and post any errors that you get (apologies for formatting): $ python >>> from ossie.utils import sb >>> c = sb.launch("SigGen")  >>> c.start()

Answer (score 1):

When the IDE launches a component within the Chalkboard environment, it provides the process a reference to the IDE's NamingContext interface for the component to register with once it's up and running.  You can see this reference as an IOR in the command line executed by the IDE.  Use "ps -ef" to view the command run.  When the process does not register with the IDE then the IDE will throw the error you described.  If the component dies and returns a non-zero error code the IDE will report that as well

The IDE has a [Console View](http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch19.html#x21-38200019.4.11) created for each process launched within the Chalkboard.  Clicking on the "Display Selected Console" menu will show you a list of consoles including the now terminated SigGen process.  This may provide you with some information if the component died during standard execution.

If the process failed to launch, there may not be any information displayed in the console.  In this case, using the python sandbox to launch the component may provide additional information as suggested by DrewC.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Somehow it was related to the proxy sever I was behind. I removed the proxy and it worked.